# Particle density controlling with image sequence not working while rendering out

Tags: rendering

I have an image of a face which i like to apply the face texture to particles. I made it by Texture Co-ordinates"from instancer" option. Then used the black and white matte image sequence of the same face to control the density of particles. In the cycles render view port its working but when i try to render it out the results are weird, seems like the colors of particles are misplaced. Any solution?
Thank You

Screen Shots:

In viewport:
[image]

Render:
[image]

Comment: you don't show us any useful information ...sorry. at least show all relevant settings by screenshots of provide an easy blend file where we can reproduce your problem

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the issue. Screenshots added.